# CakePHP 3: How to automatically log a user in after registration

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I am trying to log a user in using CakePHP 3 right after registration, but I have not been successful. This is what I am doing:

```
function register(){
    // ....
    if($result = $this->Users->save($user)){
        // Retrieves corresponding user that was just saved
        $authUser = $this->Users->get($result->id);

        // Log user in using Auth
        $this->Auth->setUser($authUser);

        // Redirect user
        $this->redirect('/users/account');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I guess posting this question opened my eyes to a fix. This is what I did to get it to work... if there is better way, I would be glad to change it...

```
function register(){
    // .... Default CakePHP generated code

    if($result = $this->Users->save($user)){
        // Retrieve user from DB
        $authUser = $this->Users->get($result->id)->toArray();

        // Log user in using Auth
        $this->Auth->setUser($authUser);

        // Redirect user
        $this->redirect(['action' => 'account']);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm giving this a go also and I tried using your code but it's not working. Variable $result seems to be uninitialized, is the error. Any ideas?

Comment: The only thing I can think of, is if you have `==` instead of `=` in your `if` statement

Comment: Ah I completely missed that, I didn't even have $result = $this->Users->save($user). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

CakePHP 3.8 × [cakephp/authentication](https://github.com/cakephp/authentication) update.

> Any place you were calling `AuthComponent::setUser()`, you should now use `setIdentity()`:
>
> ```
> // Assume you need to read a user by access token
> $user = $this->Users->find('byToken', ['token' => $token])->first();
>
> // Persist the user into configured authenticators.
> $this->Authentication->setIdentity($user);
> ```

Source: [/authentication/1/en/migration-from-the-authcomponent.html#checking-identities](https://book.cakephp.org/authentication/1/en/migration-from-the-authcomponent.html#checking-identities)